# Infer generic `this` in a base class method

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-class

I cannot make sense of how TS is inferring this generic `this`: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMA8AVAfNA3gWAFDQOgCNEBZBAFwAsB7AE1SoEsYEAPChAOzpngmTo0ACmosAXNBTMIASkkBGAEwBmaO048Y0ltAD8WaG0UAaaAE9F0AL7RJmI5KVmAXpLW2c%20Qj4BOlAFdfLixbSGgwLnMAbjwfazwE3DxQSBgAEQRfJgA3BAZ0dQ5uXjhEVAwvHzos3PzyanphWSw4n0JgGi4ICmh-GABeaDEIADoSAQbaOmbY73a%20hDG2aOgAejXoBWgAH2glNoX%200ZdVjegAB18aC6yKc2g6GiXoLhpe9hYKQ5tEoA)

```
class Base<T> {
    baseMethod<This extends Base<T>>(this: This): 123 extends This ? { x: 1, y: 1 } : { x: 2, z: 3 } {
        return {} as any;
    }
}

class Derived<T> extends Base<T> {
    derivedMethod() {
        const res = this.baseMethod();
        res.x; // 1 | 2
        res.z; // ERROR: property does not exist
    }
}
```

How is it possible that it's returning the union of both branches of the type conditional? I'd expect to return the second one (or even the first one, if `This` was somehow inferred as `any` or `unknown`. But both?)

Note 1: If I remove `<This extends Base<T>>(this: This)` and simply use `123 extends this` instead (I guess they are equivalent and I don't need `This`), the result is the same, it returns the union.

Note 2: As @caTS mentioned, if you explicitly write `derivedMethod(this: Derived<T>)` then it works. But why would TS need that?

Comment: Hover over `res` in the playground. The conditional type has not been computed yet.

Comment: On `const res` it's not computed. On the second, it is, with the union: `const res: { x: 1; y: 1;  | { x: 2;  z: 3; }`

Comment: Oh interesting: https://tsplay.dev/NB5ZVw

Comment: Oh, @caTS, I forgot to mention it, I had seen that, yes, if you are explicit in the derived method for `this`, it works. But AFICS, it should be implied! I'll add a note.

Comment: Same goes for specifying the generic on `this.baseMethod<typeHere>()`: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMA8AVAfNA3gWAFDQOgCNEBZBAFwAsB7AE1SoEsYEAPChAOzpngmTo0ACmosAXNBTMIASkkBGAEwBmaO048Y0ltAD8WaG0UAaaAE9F0AL7RJmI5KVmAXpLW2c+Qj4BOlAFdfLixbSGgwLnMAbjwfazwE3DxQSBgAEQRfJgA3BAZ0dQ5uXjhEVAwvHzos3PzyanphWSw4n0JgGi4ICmh-GABeaDEIADoSAQbaBkzsvIZlFTQRWVjvdr6EMbZo6AB6PegFaAAfaCU2jf7Rl12D6AAHXxoHrIpzaDoaLeguGl72CwKJcbIk8EA)

Comment: Just thought I'd put this out here as well: https://tsplay.dev/mbQ63N - allowing `Base` to take the child class.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be the result of the fact that typescript
defers to compute types derived from `this` inside methods
because those types might be altered in further
derived classes. This prevents it in the current version to perform even
legitimate evaluation, as expected in @tokland's question.

If we consider the example

```ts
class B {
    f() {
        let o: {x: number} extends this ? { x: 1, y: 1 } : { x: 2, z: 3 } = {} as any;
        o.x; // 1 | 2
        o.y; // ERROR: property does not exist
    }
}
```

the deferment is fully justified, since  `B` doesn't satisfy
the condition `{x: number} extends B`, but a derived class

```ts
class C extends B{
    n = 22
}
```

does. ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEBE4N))

This is similar to the case in this [typescript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16356).

The problem is that in some cases there's no
need to defer computing with `this` type; that *is the
case* in the code from OP's question, or in this "extreme"
example

```ts
class B {
    f() {
        let o: never extends this ? { x: 1, y: 1 } : { x: 2, z: 3 } = {} as any;
        o.x; // 1 | 2
        o.y; // ERROR: property does not exist
    }
}
```

([playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZX71w))

I suppose we may expect from (ask for?) future releases to improve
at this point.

OP's question may be reduced (I'll show in the end the steps I took)
to the following, more familiar version of `B`:

```ts
class B {
    f() {
        let o: 123 extends this ? { x: 1, y: 1 } : { x: 2, z: 3 } = {} as any;
        o.x; // 1 | 2
        o.z; // ERROR: property does not exist
    }
}
```

It may be corrected as per @caTS's suggestion by setting
the type of `this` in the method, and (surprisingly for me)
this case also requires replacing `this` as a type -
which still remains untouched - with `typeof this`.

```ts
class BErr2 {
    f(this: BErr2) {
        let o: 123 extends this ? { x: 1, y: 1 } : { x: 2, z: 3 } = {} as any;
        o.x; // 1 | 2
        o.z; // STILL ERROR!
    }
}

class BOk {
    f(this: BOk) {
        let o: 123 extends typeof this ? { x: 1, y: 1 } : { x: 2, z: 3 } = {} as any;
        o.x; // 1 | 2
        o.z; // OK
    }
}
```

([playground](https://tsplay.dev/Ndr7vW))

The steps I took to simplify the code from the question:

- The issue seems not to be related to inheritance, it's the same with just one class: https://tsplay.dev/Nar70m ;
- it's the same without the class parameter `T`:  https://tsplay.dev/WzPpLN
- dropping the method type parameter `This` changes somewhat
  the semantics - https://tsplay.dev/mx8bBm, but it seems the source of the error is the same.